# How to stop auto-replacement of hyphens with horizontal rule?

Tags: macos, textedit, autocorrect

If I wanted a horizontal rule, I'd type a string of em dashes. I can't find easily a way to disable this over-feature in TextEdit prefs ('Text replacement' is unticked) nor System Prefs ('Correct spelling automatically' is unticked). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Edit menu, go to Substitutions, and uncheck Smart Dashes.

Comment: That does not work as OP said.

Comment: That is not what OP said. OP specifically talked about "Text replacement"; however, unchecking this is not sufficient as you need to uncheck "Smart Dashes" too. Once "Smart Dashes" is unchecked, everything works as expected (verified on 4 Macs so far).

Comment: Then bring that in your answer

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I dislike how TextEdit puts these things (spelling/grammar too) in both app prefs and the View menu. I rarely remember to look in the latter, and I get such mixed results based on whether an option is ticked in one place but not the other.

Comment: Apparently not all apps have an edit > substitutions menu. iMessage however is one of the apps that does. Had to untick Smart Dashes there despite the fact that the system-wide setting already had this unticked in System Preferences > Keyboard > text (10.11.4)